# How to show back button in a tab bar viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a navigation controller with a home view controller on its root. Then I push a tab bar view controller. The back button disappears. How can I return from the tab bar view controller to the home view controller via back button? How can I make it visible again?

I have tried:

```
let navItem = self.navigationController?.navigationItem
let navItem2 = self.navigationItem;
leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
leftBarButton.image = UIImage(named: "arrows-back-icon-24.png")
leftBarButton.action = #selector(self.popViewController);
leftBarButton.target = self
navItem?.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
navItem2.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
```

I also have tried:

```
let navItem = self.navigationController?.navigationItem
let navItem2 = self.navigationItem;
navItem?.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
navItem2.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

All is not working. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you need to make `tabBarViewController` as `rootViewController`

Comment: Is your flow like this? UINavigationController -> UIViewController (your home vc) -> UITabBarController.

Comment: try to change to leftBarButton.action = #selector(self.navigationController?.popViewController). but first you need to confirm the workflow UINavigationController -> UIViewController(Home) -> UITabBarController

Comment: @JD. yes that's my flow.

Comment: @wskcoder the flow is like that, but the problem is the button(s) is not showing at all. Not the action that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Assign UITabBarController class file to Tab Bar Controller, just like view controller.

```
import UIKit
//this is TabBarController.swift file
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

[image]

And push it from the HomeVC like this (here, I am using UIButton for Push):

```
@IBAction func btnPush(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! TabBarController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but in my case, it was due to the viewWillAppear method. Try adding the following to each of the UIViewControllers embedded in the corresponding UITabBarController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
let btn1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "image"), for: .normal)
btn1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(methodname), for: .touchUpInside)
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1)

let btn2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
btn2.setImage(UIImage(named: "image"), for: .normal)
btn2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(methodName), for: .touchUpInside)
let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn2)  

self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([item1,item2], animated: true)
```

Try this

Comment: The problem is not the content of the buttons. The problem is that no matter what I set to that left bar button item on tabbar, it's all empty.